# Odd RuntimeError in Google foobar coding challenge

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my second challenge - it's called "guard_game".

The challenge is to create a function that recursively adds up the digits of a number until you have a single digit, and return that digit.

My solution is below, and it works just fine on my machine:

```
answers = {}

def answer(x):
     return answers[x] if answers.setdefault(x,sum(int(_) for _ in str(x))) in xrange(1,10) else answer(answers[x])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print answer(1235)
    print answer(13)
```

However, the Google foobar console is giving a `RuntimeError` on line 4. I have tried tracking down the problem by splitting the logic up into separate chunks (hard to do without being able to `print` to the console screen), and it seems to be caused by this bit: `str(x)`.

Might be relevant: the Google foobar constraints mentions code is run inside of a Python 2.7.6 sandbox. I learned using 100% Python 3, so there's a decent chance I'm doing something wrong. The constraints also say the input will be a `long` (which is same as an `int` in modern Python) between 1 and 2147483647.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Before people start in on other ways to do this: yes I'm aware of the `x % 9` trick. This question is NOT about how to complete the challenge, it's about the cause of the `RuntimeError`.

Comment: Post the complete Traceback please. Cannot duplicate problem; your solution works for me.

Comment: @wwii There is no traceback. The error only occurs in the Google foobar virtual console and it does not provide a traceback.

Comment: Well it doesn't *blow up* on a standard 32 bit windows install so maybe there is something wrong with the virtual console.

Comment: @wwii That's what I think. I submitted bug feedback to Google about it. Will probably never hear anything.

Comment: Did you find a way around this problem? I'm on a level which gives me the same error. I'm guessing they need the program to be extremely efficient in both execution time and memory usage. I've come across `MemoryError` and `Time Exceeded`. Time exceeded comes in unoptimized `for` and `while` loops. While the `MemoryError` comes when i do a `set(a list)`. Which is quite annoying, because i really want only the unique elements in my `set()`. Any pointers would be amazing! :)

Comment: @MetalloyD Nope, never did figure it out. Very annoying!!

Answer (score 3):

One thing I have noticed (This happened with another challenge called String Cleaning), too many recursive calls don't work well in Google Foobar. It simply takes too long and then never returns back anything. I optimized my code and reduced a lot of recursion calls, which then worked.

Comment: @RickTeachey With my advance in the Foobar now, I think since they want to test on the efficiency and optimization on the program, a function takes too long is discouraged. I used mem cached method to save up the result to a function call when using recursive calls during level 4 challenges. It makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!